# Bootstrap modal links overlap in IE and Chrome

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm building a site using the latest Twitter Bootstrap.

I have 3 images which link to a modal(acts as a lightbox). The middle image should be centered.

- In Firefox, it works as I would like it to.
- In Chrome, the images overlap/are too close but as you move the cursor around it kind of updates and fixes itself.
- In IE, the images overlap no matter what.

I have the site up at [www.shifteddd.com](http://www.shifteddd.com).

Answer (score 0):

you should [submit a bug report to the twitter bootstrap github project](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues). they will either tell you how to fix it, or fix it globally for the next bugfix release of their product.